# Remove sidebar from django UI

Tags: django

Whenever the user clicks on models that are shown in the sidebar list, should navigate to that model's page and the sidebar should get removed(collapse). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django projects urls.py just added the below line, then side nav bar gets removed once a model is selected.

`admin.site.enable_nav_sidebar = False`